# Не работает border для двух блоков при hover

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтоб при наведении на один блок, внизу появлялся второй блок и обводка у них была общая.

```css
.item {
 width: 220px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 10px 3px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 }

.item:hover .item_inner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 height: 100%;
}

.item_param {
 display: none;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0 5px;
 margin: 10px 0;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
 
.item_inner{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.item_inner:hover .item_param {
 display: block;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item_inner">
    TEXT
   <div class="item_param">
    <p>info</p>
    <p>info</p>
    <p>info</p>
    <p>info</p>
    <p>info</p>
    <p>info</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: У вас все работает, но кажись проблема в абсолютном значении. Вы написали "top: 100%;" что означает что второй блок будет находиться на следующем "экране" вашего браузера. (полистайте ниже)

Comment: ну да все работает..

Comment: через `inherit` свойство можно решить проблему

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Решение

```
.item_inner:hover .item_param {
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: inherit;
  border-top: none;
  width: 210px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Демо: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNgpGp

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 10px 0;` у `.item_param` дает сверху отступ - это и приводит к отсутствию у них общего отступа, или вы хотите что бы у 2х блоков была зеленая обводка?